# How can I get method's "args" argument value in while using ipdb?

Tags: python, debugging, ipdb

In `ipdb` using command `a` or `args` prints information on provided arguments for the method. How do I get actual `args` variable so I can work on the provided data?

For example when I have code:

```
class A(object):
    def test(*args, **kwargs):
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()


A().test('testing arg')
```

Then after running the code I tried:

```
ipdb> args
args = (<__main__.A object at 0x1007bdf90>, 'testing arg')
kwargs = {}
ipdb> args[0]
args = (<__main__.A object at 0x1007bdf90>, 'testing arg')
kwargs = {}
ipdb>
```

Comment: http://frid.github.io/blog/2014/06/05/python-ipdb-cheatsheet/ from there is looks like "p args" might work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Prefix your command with `!` to disable the pdb magic.

```
ipdb> !args
```

Answer (score 0):

I often set dummy variables which are part of pdb magic and then use those

```
ipdb> aa = args
```